# How do you say “Props to x”?

Tags: expressions, traduction

“Props” is used to congratulate someone.

*“Props to whoever made this!”*

*“Props to the guy who invented Reese’s.”*

*“I’ll give her my props.”*

Is there anything like this in French?

Answer (score 2):

There is "tirer son chapeau à qqu" for whomever cares to use it;

- Props to whoever made this! : Je tire mon chapeau à celui/celle qui a fait ça ! *or* Je tire mon chapeau à la personne qui a fait ça, qui qu'elle soit.
- Props to the guy who invented Reese’s. : Je tire mon chapeau au type qui a inventé le Reeses's.
- I’ll give her my props. : Je lui tire mon chapeau.

Otherwise, more sober forms of expression might be used;

- Mes/nos félicitations à …
- On doit des félicitations à …
- On peut féliciter untel pour …
- Untel mérite nos félicitations …

Mes félicitations à l'inventeur du Reese's.
Je lui présente mes félicitations.

Comment: Juste in case (you never know !), you may also hear "psartek" coming from young people : that's the arabic language that is getting more and more common amongst the french youth. That's the equivalent of it.